# Typed Query for those tables created from relationships (One to Many)

Tags: jpa, junit

I am little confused, If i have two tables related then I will have a combined table in MySQL, Since we do not have a class in our project , how would my Typed Query look in order to fetch data from table that is create from Relationship( say One to Many).

eg:

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinTable(name = "CustomerBilling",joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "Customer_Id"),
inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "Billing_Id"))
private List<Billing> billing = new ArrayList<>();
```

with the above mentioned code i will have CustomerBilling  table , So i would like to get all the records for a particular customer id. in my test (jUnit) file what Typed Query do i need to put ?

```
TypedQuery<Customer> a = em.createQuery("select b from CustomerBilling b where b.Customer_Id =?1", Customer.class);
```

This did not work Since CustomerBilling abstrate schema is not present.

Thanks
Prashanth

Answer (score 0):

I am sure you have classes in your project as it is java based :)

Reading between the lines, you mean, that you have 3 tables in DB Customer, Billing and CustomerBilling, but only 2 entities in JPA the Customer and Billing as the CustomerBilling is there only to store the relation. (But your example of typed query tries to get Customer.class as the result so maybe I am wrong).

You don't reference jointable objects directly (unless they are mapped).
You can query by Customer, or by Billing but not by CustomerBilling. If there is no such entity defined in JPA, there is nothing that JPA can query about.

And you shouldn't try to do it, even for unit testing (BTW jpa tests are integration tests not unit tests). 
The whole point of mapping the relationships with @OnteToMany and such is to hide, from the program, the actual DB structure. So you should access Billings of a customer, or customer for a billing, not the relation info. 
Currently the relation is stored by join table, but it could be change it to join column and whole program logic would stay the same (and so should the tests).

You should test, that if you add bilings to customer and save them, you correctly retrieves them, that if you remove the biling from customer it disappears, but there is no reason to check the content of the join table.

Finally, if you really must, you can use native sql query to access CustomerBilling table

```
em.createNativeQuery
```

or
you can change your mappings, and introdude the CustomerBilling entity, and map your OneToMay on Customer to the CustomerBilling instead of Directly Billing.